# Hibernate search collection total

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Say I have a `resolution` with an `ArrayList` collection of `refund` objects, with an integer of `amount`.

The end result is I want to search on `resolution`s on the sum of `refund`'s `amount`s, without use of HQL.

Currently I am doing this by summing in MySQL which is clumsy, but it maintains normalisation and I can guarantee it is correct.

A way I thought of doing this is by having a `refundTotal` in `resolution`, which would be a field in the database. I have a private 0 argument setter that loops through `refund`, sums the `amount` and stores it when the flush happens. The setter is run on database retrieval, so its correct when it comes out of the database. The getter ensures its correct whenever its needed should it be needed.

```
private setRefundTotal(){
   ArrayList<Refund> refunds = getRefunds();
   Integer refundTotalSum = 0;
   for(refunds as Refund refund){
      refundTotalSum+=refund.getAmount();
   }
   this.refundTotal = refundTotalSum;
}

public integer getRefundTotal(){
   this.setRefundTotal();
   return totalRefund;
}
```

If I update a `refund` in isolation of `resolution` however, I have to get and save the `resolution` so the `refundTotal` stays consistent.

I'm sure this is an extremely common scenario that hibernate has a solution for?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use `@Formula` to replace collection of refund, something like this:

```
@Formula(value = "select sum(t.amount) from User_Transaction t where t.abstractenvelope_id = id")
private Long total;
```

see detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096053/hibernate-property-based-on-sum)